# Use custom value for preferredFramesPerSecond

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I would like to get get my ARkit app running at an specific number of frames per second (25 fps in my case). I can get this by modifying this parameter: [preferredFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink/1648421-preferredframespersecond) but it always sets 30 fps, not 25.
It works ok for 5, 15, 20, 30, 45 or 60, but why not for 25 fps?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    sceneView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 25
    ...
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Instance property `preferredFramesPerSecond` is for the preferred frame rate for the display link callback but not for the camera.

```
var preferredFramesPerSecond: Int { get set }
```

> When you specify a preferred frame rate for a display link, it notifies the target at a rate as close as possible based on the capabilities on the hardware and other tasks your game or app may be executing. **The actual frame rate chosen is usually a factor of the maximum refresh rate of the screen to provide a consistent frame rate**. For example, if the maximum refresh rate of the screen is 60 frames per second, that is also the highest frame rate the display link sets as the actual frame rate. However, if you ask for a lower frame rate, the display link might choose 30, 20, or 15 frames per second, or another rate, as the actual frame rate. Choose a frame rate that your app can consistently maintain.

A running AR session continuously captures video frames from the device camera. For each frame, ***ARKit analyzes the image together with data from the device's motion sensing hardware*** to estimate the device's real-world position. ARKit delivers this tracking information and imaging parameters in the form of an ARFrame object.

[image]

[image]

> **Frame rate for robust Augmented Reality must be 60 fps minimum.**

But I have to notice that Front-Facing Depth Image Camera in iPhone X captures zDepth image at 15 Hz (`AVDepthData` at 15 fps) instead of regular RGB image that must be captured at 60 Hz.

[image]

To ask ARKit for a Frame Camera Position you can using the methods listed here (to build a custom `AR View` by rendering camera images and using position-tracking information to display overlay content): [Displaying an AR Experience with Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/displaying_an_ar_experience_with_metal).

Or use an approach like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sceneView.delegate = self          // ARSCNViewDelegate
        sceneView.session.delegate = self  // ARSessionDelegate
    } 

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        let currentTransform = frame.camera.transform
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Corrected as per your suggestion

Comment: Is the rate of frames positions I need for an specific use case

Comment: Give me details for your specific case, please.

Answer (score 0):

The framerate is calculated as following:

```
fps = maxFrameRate/interval
```

So if `maxFrameRate = 60` and the interval goes from `1 to 60` we get the following fps values:

```
interval 1 => fps: double 60 int: 60
interval 2 => fps: double 30 int: 30
interval 3 => fps: double 20 int: 20
interval 4 => fps: double 15 int: 15
interval 5 => fps: double 12 int: 12
interval 6 => fps: double 10 int: 10
interval 7 => fps: double 8.571428571428571 int: 8
interval 8 => fps: double 7.5 int: 7
interval 9 => fps: double 6.666666666666667 int: 6
interval 10 => fps: double 6 int: 6
interval 11 => fps: double 5.454545454545454 int: 5
interval 12 => fps: double 5 int: 5
interval 13 => fps: double 4.615384615384615 int: 4
interval 14 => fps: double 4.285714285714286 int: 4
interval 15 => fps: double 4 int: 4
interval 16 => fps: double 3.75 int: 3
interval 17 => fps: double 3.5294117647058822 int: 3
interval 18 => fps: double 3.3333333333333335 int: 3
interval 19 => fps: double 3.1578947368421053 int: 3
interval 20 => fps: double 3 int: 3
interval 21 => fps: double 2.857142857142857 int: 2
interval 22 => fps: double 2.727272727272727 int: 2
interval 23 => fps: double 2.608695652173913 int: 2
interval 24 => fps: double 2.5 int: 2
interval 25 => fps: double 2.4 int: 2
interval 26 => fps: double 2.3076923076923075 int: 2
interval 27 => fps: double 2.2222222222222223 int: 2
interval 28 => fps: double 2.142857142857143 int: 2
interval 29 => fps: double 2.0689655172413794 int: 2
interval 30 => fps: double 2 int: 2
interval 31 => fps: double 1.935483870967742 int: 1
interval 32 => fps: double 1.875 int: 1
interval 33 => fps: double 1.8181818181818181 int: 1
interval 34 => fps: double 1.7647058823529411 int: 1
interval 35 => fps: double 1.7142857142857142 int: 1
interval 36 => fps: double 1.6666666666666667 int: 1
interval 37 => fps: double 1.6216216216216217 int: 1
interval 38 => fps: double 1.5789473684210527 int: 1
interval 39 => fps: double 1.5384615384615385 int: 1
interval 40 => fps: double 1.5 int: 1
interval 41 => fps: double 1.4634146341463414 int: 1
interval 42 => fps: double 1.4285714285714286 int: 1
interval 43 => fps: double 1.3953488372093024 int: 1
interval 44 => fps: double 1.3636363636363635 int: 1
interval 45 => fps: double 1.3333333333333333 int: 1
interval 46 => fps: double 1.3043478260869565 int: 1
interval 47 => fps: double 1.2765957446808511 int: 1
interval 48 => fps: double 1.25 int: 1
interval 49 => fps: double 1.2244897959183674 int: 1
interval 50 => fps: double 1.2 int: 1
interval 51 => fps: double 1.1764705882352942 int: 1
interval 52 => fps: double 1.1538461538461537 int: 1
interval 53 => fps: double 1.1320754716981132 int: 1
interval 54 => fps: double 1.1111111111111112 int: 1
interval 55 => fps: double 1.0909090909090908 int: 1
interval 56 => fps: double 1.0714285714285714 int: 1
interval 57 => fps: double 1.0526315789473684 int: 1
interval 58 => fps: double 1.0344827586206897 int: 1
interval 59 => fps: double 1.0169491525423728 int: 1
interval 60 => fps: double 1 int: 1
```

So as you can see the fps value never becomes 25, but goes like 60, 30, 20, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1